# Restrict Users to access _layouts/viewlsts.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, layout, restrict

I have a sharepoint site.
But I am facing a problem that anyone can access my list and libraries by _layouts/viewlsts.aspx.

Please Reply....

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an OOTB feature to use for this called ViewFormPagesLockdown which is the best practice way to go, rather than modifying web.config directly.
Read more here: http://salaudeen.blogspot.se/2010/03/viewformpageslockdown-lock-down-form.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify in the web.config file to deny the access.
See this [article](http://balmikighosh.blogspot.in/2012/03/restrict-access-for-anonymous-users.html).